# Time complexity of copying a Collection of strings to another in Java

Tags: java, string, collections, time-complexity

I have a couple of questions about how the add function of a Java `Collection` handles strings. For example, in the below code snippet, I am copying a `List` of strings to a `HashSet`. What is the worst-case total time complexity in this case? Is it O(M x N) or O(N), where M is the max length of any string in the list, and N is the total number of strings in the list.

```
public HashSet<String> createDict(List<String> wordList) {
   HashSet<String> wordDict = new HashSet<>();
   for(String word : wordList) {
       wordDict.add(word);
   }
   return wordDict;
}
```

Will the time complexity be exactly the same if I use the below code instead of the loop?

```
HashSet<String> wordDict = new HashSet<>(wordList);
```

Comment: *"Is it O(M x N) or O(N), where M is the max length of any string in the list [...]"*, could you explain that? Why does the length affect the copy process? And why does it multiply with N?

Comment: The length(N) of the list affects the copy process because I am running a loop to traverse all the strings in the list. But my question is, does the max length(M) of a particular string also affects the time complexity of the copy? If yes, why?

Comment: It doesn't, which has to do with how a `HashSet` adds elements and works. See below answers that provide the informations about that. *But* this is the realistic answer. You could argue that the length M has to be read at least once. Reading is done character by character and if you do it for every n then the complexity is indeed *O(M x N)*. But this is the "I'm taking *O* notation extremly serious" answer.

Comment: No strings are being copied by value, only by reference, so their length is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Length of Strings has nothing to do with copying elements between collections. In fact, you don't copy Strings themselves but references to them. So the complexity will be O(N).

When it comes to the second question about `new HashSet<>(wordList)` - this call will be faster than than doing a loop. The reason for that is that in `HashSet(Collection)` constructor it first checks the size of that collection and starts with initialCapacity based on that. This way it doesn't have to resize the underlying HashMap that often.

For those who are curious and too lazy to search, this is `HashSet`s constructor in question:

```
public HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    map = new HashMap<>(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 16));
    addAll(c);
}
```

And `addAll` from `AbstractCollection`:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c)
        if (add(e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
```

So if you were to set initialCapacity in your example code you will get the same performance, like so:

```
public HashSet<String> createDict(List<String> wordList) {
   int initialCapacity = Math.max((int) (wordList.size()/.75f) + 1, 16);
   HashSet<String> wordDict = new HashSet<>(initialCapacity );
   for(String word : wordList) {
       wordDict.add(word);
   }
   return wordDict;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what happens if I copy the strings from a list to another list? Will it be O(N) as well?

Comment: It will be exactly the same.

Comment: Whether the initial capacity has any effect, depends on how many duplicates the original list has.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity will be O(N).

Adding an item to an `HashSet` is O(1) and it won't compare strings char by char, which is probably how you would get O(MxN).

Yes, creating the `HashSet` passing the list in the constructor will have the same complexity. 
Actually you can check `HashSet` implementation code and it does exactly the same thing you did, except for a more optimised object creation based on your list size.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` is implemented using `HashTable`. Which means, it has `O(1)` insertion and is using hash function to insert an element. In this case, size of the inserted element does not really matter much, and they all are considered to be `O(1)`. So your overall, code has `O(N)` complexity, where `N` is the size of your list.